# golang field inheritance without nested initializing

Tags: go, inheritance

Is it possible to inherit without object initializer?

```
type BaseEmployee struct{
    LastName string
}

type Employee struct {
 Name string,
 BaseEmployee
}
```

Right now I have this:

```
ob := Employee {
  FirstName: "Ron"
  LastName : BaseEmployee {LastName : "Howard"}
}
```

BUT I want to achieve something like this:

```
ob := Employee {
  FirstName: "Ron"
  LastName : "Howard",//<<<<<<<<<---- how us that possible?
}
```

Possible?

Comment: No. this is all wrong. Do not try to mimic inheritance based OPP and code reuse in Go: It doesn't work, no matter how hard you try and you will just get frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment left on your question, there is no way to "implicitly" link struct fields to two different structs.

If it's the struct initialization syntax you object to, you could get around this by just writing a convenience function to initialize a new BaseEmployee, e.g.:

```
func NewBaseEmployee(name string) BaseEmployee {
    return BaseEmployee{LastName: name}
}

ob := Employee {
    FirstName: "Ron"
    LastName : NewBaseEmployee("Howard")
}
```

Comment: @SamHolmes I think your comment should be directed to the original question, not to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was eventually did